# Please login with your GNOME Account (online account)

Tags: gnome, login, password, google, online-accounts

In trying to login to gnome [paste](https://paste.gnome.org/user/login), " Please login with your GNOME Account", I get `Authentication failed, please try again.` -- fair enough.  But what are my login credentials?  How do I find them?

[image: online]

So far as I can tell, it would be my "online" account through GNOME, specifically the Google account as above.  I wouldn't expect an online account to have a password per se, but to use `OAuth` or similar..

How do online accounts work?  Specifically for GNOME paste.

Comment: There is no need to login to use paste tho. Simply use https://paste.gnome.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accounts on the GNOME web site have nothing to do with *Online Accounts* or your account on your computer. If you wish to log in to the web site, you will need an account on the GNOME web site, which one generally gets by becoming a member of the GNOME.org community.